# How can I intitalize the status of the active theme in my component?

Tags: delphi, themes, delphi-2009

I work on a theme aware component and when I create it I must set the initial status with `IsThemeActive` (from UxTheme unit). But if I use this function in the component `constructor`, I get Access Violation. Using it anywhere else it works fine. What is happening and how can I set an initial status if I can't do it in `OnCreate` ?

My component unit:

```
unit TestUnit;

interface

uses Classes, Windows, Controls, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, CommCtrl, Messages, Forms,
     SysUtils, Graphics, UxTheme;

type
  TSuperList = class(TListView)
  private
    FThemeEnabled: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TSuperList.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 FThemeEnabled:= IsThemeActive;
end;

end.
```

Using it in the application:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 List1:= TSuperList.Create(Form1);
 List1.Parent:= Form1;
end;
```

Comment: Ok, so we know for sure that it can't be called in the constructor... Now, where should I call it, so I can read the initial status ?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I updated the question with the minimal example.

Comment: I also try to use `IsThemeActive` in the `initialization` section... It fails too !

Comment: I can't, because my component doesn't have `OnShow` event. But I found what was wrong ! I must call first `InitThemeLibrary`... :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. I had to initialize the theme library first :

```
unit TestUnit;

interface

uses Classes, Windows, Controls, ComCtrls, StdCtrls, CommCtrl, Messages, Forms,
     SysUtils, Graphics, UxTheme;

type
  TSuperList = class(TListView)
  private
    FThemeEnabled: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

implementation

var IsThemeEnabled: Boolean;

constructor TSuperList.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited;
 FThemeEnabled:= IsThemeEnabled;
end;

initialization

 InitThemeLibrary;
 IsThemeEnabled:= IsThemeActive;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested such a situation with my own custom component and there is no any `AccessViolation`. Maybe it is because of I'm using `Delphi Tokyo 10.2`.

### 1. Get themes status

But as a one thought: you can override `CreateWnd` procedure to call `IsThemeActive` function instead of doing this in `constructor` section.

Something like this:

```
procedure TSuperList.CreateWnd;
begin
  Inherited CreateWnd;
  FThemeEnabled := UXTheme.IsThemeActive;
end;
```

There is no need to explicitly initialize theme library.

### 2. Properly handling accsessibility of themes

Also I would like to mention that it is important to check if your application applied visual style(-es), because OS can use visual style for now, but your application not. Thus, `IsThemeActive` function returns `True` while your application has no applied themes. It will result in painting your component *themed* while another components will be painted *non-themed*.
You can use `IsAppThemed` function to check if application uses themes at current moment.

Important note for `IsAppThemed`:

> Prior to Windows 8, a visual style can be turned off in Control Panel, so that an application can support visual styles but not have a visual style applied at a given time.
>   In Windows 8, it is not possible to turn off visual styles.

You can be wondered: why these both functions returns `True` even if my applcation *visually* is not themed and OS has themes enabled?

I have no answer for this. Only one circumstance under that `IsThemeActive` function returns `True` and `IsAppThemed` function returns `False` is when visual appearance is disabled *specifically for you application*.  Image below depicts how to achieve this (in Russian a bit):

[image]
Check box above red line is intended to be "Checked" to disable application theming while OS has themes activated.

Picture below displays what kind of appearance will `TForm` have with disabled visual themes for application (via way described above that is where `IsAppThemed` returns `False`), and with active application theming (`IsAppThemed` returns `True`).
Note: on the left side is standard `notepad.exe` application which has no focus and is themed in both cases.

[image]

So playing with themes is not trivial as it could be.

Sources:

- [UXTheme library methods DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/)
- [function IsThemeActive DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-isthemeactive/)
- [function IsAppThemed DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-isappthemed/)